# How to remove the pre header line item of a CSV file using csv.DictReader

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary, utf-8, reader

I would like to remove the first line from a csv file like below which comes with the encode type, so when I`m reading that file with csv.DictReader it is recognizing this word as a key from the dictionary.
csv input: (raw_file_data)

```
UTF-8,,,,
POSID,POST1,VERNR,PBUKR,PWPOS
"B00007","testing",08027011,"0030","CNY"
```

code to read it:

```
for row in csv.DictReader(codecs.getreader(encoding="ISO-8859-1")(raw_file_data)):
    data_list.append(row)
```

the result is that the first line of CSV is being considered as a key and that`s my issue, can anyone help me to just ignore that first line and consider the csv reader since the second line which contains the header information?, I tried something with next(), but I could not solve it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the first line by calling `next` on the file iterator before you pass it to `csv.DictReader`:

```
file = codecs.getreader(encoding="ISO-8859-1")(raw_file_data)
next(file)
for row in csv.DictReader(file):
    data_list.append(row)
```